# I can't get CompletableFuture supplyAsync method to return anything

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm experimenting with the CompletableFuture class from Java 8.  I've written a simple class that returns a CompletableFuture.  The problem is that the get method blocks forever.  I ran the overloaded get() method with the delay and time unit params, and it gives me a timeout exception.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my code.

```
class FutureExampleWithComposition {
    public Future<String> calculateAsync() {
         CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        cf.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello");
         return cf;
    }
}
```

Below, I run the calculateAsync method from the class as follows:

```
try {
            Future<String> cf1 = f1.calculateAsync();
            System.out.println(cf1.get(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Check the signature of `supplyAync` (hint... it's static)

Comment: Yup.  That was it. I forgot that supplyAsync() is static.  Thanks much